# How to select two or more elements from the same node with Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to select two elements from the same node. Here the code:

```
<div >
  <span >First element to select:</span>
  <span ></span>
  <strong >Second element to select</strong>
</div>
```

I have tried with this:

```
$x('//div/span/text()')
```

and I get an array like this:

```
["First element", " "]
```

Is there anyway to get:

```
["First element", "Second element"]
```

and perhaps to put this into an python dictionary? and have:

```
dict = {'First element' : 'Second element'}
```

Many thanks for helping

Comment: There is not node that matches `[@id="details"]`. Please [edit] your question and include HTML that matches your code.

Comment: What is `$x`? This is not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath :

```
//*[@id="details"]//div/*/text()
```

or if you specifically want to get text nodes only from `span` and `strong` :

```
//*[@id="details"]//div/*[self::span|self::strong]/text()
```

to skip empty text nodes, add a predicate `[normalize-space()]` :

```
//*[@id="details"]//div/*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: Super! Thanks! but this generates this ["First element", " ", "Second element"] though. Is possible to generate ["First element", "Second element"] only?

Comment: @user1463152 check the 3rd XPath in my answer

Comment: @user1463152 no problem. Don't forget to accept the answer since it solves the problem in question. More info : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work